# How can I get the array index of a given object in C# with control arrays?

Tags: c#, .net, controls, event-handling, control-array

I am dynamically adding a bunch of controls to a form. Each control calls the same method, and in that method I need to know the array index of the the control that performed the action.

```
CheckBox[] myCB = new CheckBox[100];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    myCB[i] = new CheckBox();
    myCB[i].Text = "Clicky!";
    myCB[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(dynamicbutton_Click);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myCB[i]);
}

private void dynamicbutton_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = sender.???array index property???.ToString();
}
```

So if I click `myCB[42]` `label1` will read "42"  Of course, if there is an easier way to handle dynamic controls I'd appreciate pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious solution would be to set the tag:

```
CheckBox[] myCB = new CheckBox[100];
for (int i = 0; i < myCB.Length; i++)
{
    myCB[i] = new CheckBox();
    myCB[i].Text = "Clicky!";
    myCB[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(dynamicbutton_Click);
    myCB[i].Tag = i;
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myCB[i]);
}
```

Then:

```
private void dynamicbutton_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control) sender;
    label1.Text = sender.Tag.ToString();
}
```

Another alternative is to capture the information in the event handler, most simply using a lambda expression or anonymous method:

```
CheckBox[] myCB = new CheckBox[100];
for (int i = 0; i < myCB.Length; i++)
{
    int index = i; // This is very important, as otherwise i will
                  // be captured for all of them
    myCB[i] = new CheckBox();
    myCB[i].Text = "Clicky!";
    myCB[i].Click += (s, e) => label1.Text = index.ToString();
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myCB[i]);
}
```

or for more complicated behaviour:

```
CheckBox[] myCB = new CheckBox[100];
for (int i = 0; i < myCB.Length; i++)
{
    int index= i; // This is very important, as otherwise i will
                  // be captured for all of them
    myCB[i] = new CheckBox();
    myCB[i].Text = "Clicky!";
    myCB[i].Click += (s, e) => DoSomethingComplicated(index, s, e);
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myCB[i]);
}
```

(where you declare `DoSomethingComplicated` appropriately).

Comment: Why do you need to declare a new local variable, aren't you just assigning a value which is changing each time? I mean, index.ToString() returns a new string instance, doesn't it?

Comment: Without the new local variable, the "i" variable is captured: not the value, but the variable itself. That means when you clicked on the label, it would set the value to 100 every time. Try it! This is a well-known issue with captured variables and loops.

Comment: This is a feature, not a bug.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

Comment: I'd say it's a feature in the "for" loop, but a flaw in language design for the "foreach" loop: it certainly *looks* like a new variable is being created in each declaration of the loop with foreach. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/969729 for more discussion on this.)

Comment: @SLaks, it has nothing to do directly with closures, but to whether a loop creates a new local variable on each iteration or it reuses a (n implicit) variable declared just outside the loop. Closures will manifest the same 'problem' if you use a while and a variable declared outside.

Comment: @Vinko: It absolutely has to do with closures. It's only because it's a closure that the *variable* is captured rather than just its value at the point of the delegate creation.

Answer (score 5):

```
private void dynamicbutton_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = Array.IndexOf(myCB, (CheckBox)sender).ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest answer, although not efficient for large number of checkboxes. For better performance it's probably better to use the Tag property of the checkbox.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I think that Jon and Rein are right - tags are a better general solution for this problem than finding the index.

Answer (score 3):

Control's should have a Tag property. Maybe you can attach the index to the Tag. You will incur boxing though...

Comment: If he's explicitly looking for the index rather than an arbitrary ID/indicator, then this probably isn't the best way.

Comment: Well he did explicitly state: "Of course, if there's an easier way to handle dynamic controls I'd appreciate pointers...." Finding the index each time is horribly inefficient IMO.

Comment: Given that the code is being executed on a button click, and that there are only 100 to check through, efficiency is hardly going to be a big issue!

Comment: In particular, it associates the information with the object itself, which I view as a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
int j = i;
myCB[i].Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
 // here you can use "j"

};
```

Comment: Ooh, I like the use of closures to do this - that's pretty novel.

Comment: you could use i, but i would be 100. You would want to declare a new variable "int j = i; then use j within the delegate.

Comment: To do this, you MUST declare a separate variable inside the loop and assign it to i.

`i` itself will be equal to 100 in all of the delegates, which is not what you want.

Comment: Downvoted until the use of "i" is changed to reflect SLaks comment. See my answer for an example of how to do this safely.

Comment: @Jon: do I get my 2 points back even though someone else did the edit?